# Create css from scss, then move to a specific folder, but do not include in header

Tags: webpack

I have an `angular 6` app, which uses `webpack 4` (I'm not using the `ng cli`) and has this structure:

```
myNgApp/
├── config/
│   ├── webpack.common.js
│   ├── webpack.dev.js
│   ├── webpack.prod.js
|   ├── // other webpack related scripts
└── src/
    └─ app/
       ├─ themes/
       |    ├── dark.theme.scss
       |    └── blue.theme.scss
       ├─ components/
       ├─ app.component.scss
       ├─ app.component.html
       ├─ app.component.ts
       ├─ app.module.ts

 ... // More files
```

What I want to achieve is:

- create separate css files [`app.css`, `vendor.css`, `dark.theme.css`, `blue.theme.css`]
- move the 2 main css files (`app.css`, `vendor.css`) to folder `dist/css` and include them into `head` tag of my application
- move the theme files (`dark.theme.css`, `blue.theme.css`) to folder `dist/css/themes`, but do not include them to my apps `head`tag (I want to manage the themes through my application)

So my bundle should look like this:

```
myNgApp/
├── dist/
│   ├── css/
│   │    ├── themes/
│   │    │    ├── dark.theme.css
│   │    │    ├── blue.theme.css
│   │    │
│   │    ├─ app.css    
|   |    └─ vendor.css
│   │
│   └── // other files    
│
├── config.sh
└── install.bat
 ... // More files
```

My current `webpack.common.js`:

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    "polyfills": "./src/polyfills.ts",
    "vendor": "./src/vendor.ts",
    "app": "./src/main.ts"
},

resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app/themes")
            ],
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: '../'
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                        includePaths: [
                            path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/app/")
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your entry key as the output destination, based on your output path. So 1st you need an `output`...

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename: "[name].js"
}
```

Now your `entry: {"app": "./src/main.ts"}` will go to dist; `dist/app.js`

Add entries for `where the file should go based on dist: where the file is now`. Keep in mind that you'll get an extra `js` file for every `scss` file, but you can delete/ignore them.

```
entry: {
    "polyfills": "./src/polyfills.ts",
    "vendor": "./src/vendor.ts",
    "app": "./src/main.ts",
    "./css": "path-to-app.scss",
    "./css": "path-to-vendor.scss",
    "./css/themes: "path-to-blue.theme.scss",
    "./css/themes: "path-to-dark.theme.scss",
}
```

Also, w/this^ setup, I think you only need 1 rule for all your styles...

```
    {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: { sourceMap: true }
            },
            {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: { sourceMap: true }
            }
        ]
    }
```